# How to Compare classes having arrayList which in turn have class object which too have arrayList

Tags: c#-4.0

How to compare?

```
class A
{

       B b;

       ArrayList aobj;
}

class B
{

      ArrayList bobj;
}
```

Now,

```
A Object1=new A();

A Object2=new A();

Object1 == Object2 ?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to overload the `== operator` for `Class A`. The exact implementation depends on how you would want to define `==`, but typically this would be a attribute by attribute comparison. So for you case check if the b members are equal and then check if the ArrayList are equal in length and have same elements.